# Perl, ppm, and trying to download module dependencies

Tags: perl

I have Strawberry Perl and PPM installed.  I am no stranger to installing modules by hand from CPAN, but recently came into one of those situations where a module required one dependency and -that- dependency required twenty..

So I decided to give PPM a whirl (because that automatically installs dependencies, right?), and I initially thought it worked like Ruby Gems.  I loaded it and typed:

```
ppm> install OLE::Storage_Lite
```

from this [tutorial](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-pexcel/).

Then I ran into the problem saying 'Could not locate a PPDfile'.

So I followed this [tutorial](http://kobesearch.cpan.org/htdocs/Spreadsheet-WriteExcel/INSTALL.html) which walks you through hooking up a link to a repository, and it still couldn't find the PPD file.

My question is: Can anyone help me load a Perl module so I can read and write from Excel files!?

Solved: My problem turned out to be a proxy server at work that wouldn't allow me to download packages through PPM.

Comment: The cpan client will automatically install dependencies for you too; you just need to set the right configuration value.

Comment: Ether: Strawberry has this setting by default, and in other dists it is set to 'ask'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things:

1. CPAN can install dependencies too!  :)  just do a `cpan install My::Module` on the command line to get your module and its dependencies installed.
2. Use `Win32::OLE` instead.

`Win32::OLE` is the standard module for interacting with COM and OLE objects in windows, and it works great.  It's already included with Strawberry Perl, and it works well!  You just need to look at the documents regarding Perl and 'OLE Automation'.  It would look something like this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Win32::OLE; 
use Win32::OLE::Const 'Microsoft Excel';  # brin in Excel constants

my $excel = Win32::OLE->new('Excel.Application') or die "oops\n";
```

In fact, if you check out the [Win32::OLE](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Win32%3a%3aOLE) docs on CPAN, you'll see that they have several examples right there on how to get Excel automation working.

After that, a quick search for "Excel OLE Automation" will bring up a lot of tutorials showing you all the methods you need to call and quirks of Excel.  But after that, it's pretty straight forward!  Some examples:

```
my $sheet = $excel->Worksheets(1);  #Gets the first worksheet, 1 indexed
$sheet->Cells($row, $col); # do something to a cell 
$sheet->Columns("A:D");    # do something to some columns
$sheet->Rows($row_number); # do something to a row
```

There's obviously a lot more (The excel API is pretty vast) but this should get ya started.

Comment: This should be obvious, but using [OLE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_Linking_and_Embedding) requires you to have Excel installed. This is unlikely to be a problem if you're developing on and for Windows. Spreadsheet::WriteExcel allows you to create an Excel spreadsheet without having Excel installed -- even from other platforms.

Comment: Ah, not obvious at all, to me.  Bummer.  Personally, I'd be hesitant to write excel documents outside of excel itself for incompatibility reasons.  Reading and writing to Excel is a pain for a lot of reasons...Lotus 1-2-3 compatibility is just one of them. :)

Comment: Hi guys.  My problem turned out to be a proxy server at work that wouldn't allow me to download packages through PPM.  I couldn't even use wget.  However, I am going to mark this solution as correct because it is very insightful.

Comment: I just want to say that Win32::OLE is a very crappy module.  It's slow, and old, and barely maintained.  The only reason why I used it was because my work's proxy server doesn't allow me to use ppm or cpan, and it required very little dependencies.  So if anyone reads this page I hope they read this comment before they use it.